# GCP Workload Identity Federation with custom server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid-connect

I'm not really sure what the correct terminology is to explain this. Basically I want to make my own self-hosted OIDC server to use for a Google Cloud Workload Provider. The same way a CI platform would authenticate with GCP using its own built-in JWT, I want to do that but with my own application that generates a JWT with my own private key and lets Google validate that JWT against my own verification server.

I have no idea what to even google to figure out how to do this. I'm just asking what the correct terminology for this is because I can't seem to find any OIDC server examples showing this exact type of flow.

I basically just need to know what Google's request to the issuer URL looks like, and what I need to respond with.

Comment: Have you implemented WIF with other OIDC service providers such as Azure or GitHub? Once you do, that will show you the HTTP requests and responses. Start with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) which includes supporting any OIDC service provider.

Comment: @JohnHanley Is there a name for this type of server with a documented standard for the requests and responses? There must be some standard if many different platforms integrate it, that's all I'm trying to figure out. I can't find any OIDC examples that don't involve a username/password with redirect URI and all that. I have it implemented with GitHub currently but that doesn't show me the request details. I need to see the request Google is making to the issuing server to validate GitHub's token.

Comment: Workload Identity Federation is a Google product. The interface is to OIDC, which is a standard. The reason you don't find any examples is that OIDC is built on OAuth as a layer. You could fake a lot of stuff. The OIDC response is simple JSON with a number of documented keys. However, you are biting into a big project. Unless you have a good reason, use one of the open source OAuth identity provider packages.

Comment: @JohnHanley Basically, I want to generate my own JWTs with specific claims that grant access to very specific resources, and then pass those JWTs to many microservices to grant them access to what they need securely (outside GCP on secure private networks). I'd like to do this so that the permissions can be entirely defined by the claims in the token rather than an individual service account for every single node that needs access. Is this the right solution for that?

Comment: No, this is not the right solution for that. Also, you cannot generate your own tokens. Tokens are signed by a Google private key. Some services require OAuth Access Tokens and others require OIDC Identity Tokens. Use normal Google authorization to obtain those tokens.

Comment: @JohnHanley Then how does a service like GitHub Actions work? From my understanding, GitHub generates a JWT with their private key, you send that to Google, Google goes back to GitHub to ask if it matches their private key, and then lets you in if so. I want to perform whatever interaction GitHub is performing with Google and do whatever GitHub is doing but with my own application.

Comment: GitHub is acting as an OAuth Identity Provider. That is standard and well documented. You need to make up your mind, are you going to follow the standard, then use WIF, if not then you must use standard Google authorization.

Comment: As a side note study Google Cloud STS. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/sts/rest

Comment: @JohnHanley Right yeah sorry if I went off on a tangent, I am trying to implement a standard at the end of the day. Thank you that info does help. I was just confused during research because all the examples on the internet for OIDC/OAuth servers are for more common use-cases like username/password for a front-end app. I'm going to try [node-oidc-provider](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider) and see if I can figure it out with that.